# Consuming external api using webclient

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, webclient

I am having list of urls. I'm trying to consume jsondata from those api's. Below is the code which i tried but I'm getting **Mono.flatMapMany-> at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.bodyToFlux(DefaultWebClient.java:554)**

If I use .block() I'm getting the jsonData for those api's but the thing is it becomes synchronous when i use .block(). I want it to be async. Can anyone help me out.

Thanks in advance.

```
List<String> urls=getUrls();
Flux<String> k=null;
for(int i=0;i<urls.size();i++){
    k=webClientBuilder.
      build.get().
      uri(urls.get(i)).retrieve().
      bodyToFlux(String.class);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code snippet you have provided so I would advise you firstly to have a read through the [project reactor reference documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/)

The code snippet below will hopefully achieve what you are looking for. Though if the desire is to run this as part of a reactive pipeline, you will want to return the `Flux` from this method instead of subscribing. The underlying framework (spring boot in this case) will initiate the subscription.

```java
        List<String> urls = Arrays.asList("https://google.com", "https://yahoo.com");
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().build();

        Flux.fromStream(urls.stream())
                .flatMap(url -> webClient.get()
                        .uri(url)
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToMono(String.class))
                .doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("Response: " + s))
                .subscribe();
```

Comment: I just have another doubt. How can I add those responses in a map and use it later. I'm new to spring reactive and having some difficulties.

Comment: please try and keep each post to a single question. If you have a separate question, please raise this as a separate question